# shape-outside and vertically aligned text

Tags: css, webkit, vertical-alignment, polygon, css-shapes

How do I align the text inside a block vertically? I cannot do that without braking the element on the left side which has a `shape-outside` property.

```css
.a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b {
  float: left;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.c {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

The image displays what I have and what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: example]

The height of the parent element and length of text is not fixed.

Comment: Shape-outside is a fairly new property, and has little/weak browser support. Hence there's actually quite a lot that'll break this

Comment: This would be no problem if shape-inside was supported.

Comment: [I would hardly say the shape-outside property was supported, realistically](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc(50% + 30px);` for `padding-top`

[calc is support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

http://jsfiddle.net/yt4py6oa/5/

```
.c {
    position:relative;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-top: calc(50% + 30px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to need vertical center alignment. In that case you need to give a height to your 'c' container. say 1/3rd of parent container.

Then apply : (height of a-height of c)/2

and set it as padding top of 'c'.

Answer (score -1):

```
just put **padding-top:100px;** to "c" class,

.c {
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slokuliyana/yt4py6oa/1/

Comment: The text content and the box height varies.